# How to Integrate angular 4 or higher with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

i want to integrate angular 4 or higher than that with my existing express folder.

As i am new to mean stack development i want clean and understandable steps how to integrate angular with express.

Anyone having reference links for the following::

- How to integrate express and angular
- how to use mongoose in it.
- And crud example for mean app development.

Answer (score 2):

1. Integrating Angular and Express can be done through a single `server.js` file placed in the root directory of your Angular project.  Use Angular CLI to `ng build --prod` and generate a `dist/` folder.  You can then link the `dist/` folder through the following code in your `server.js` file and running `node server.js`.

   ```
   // Define variables
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();

   // Use the /dist directory
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

   // Catch all other invalid routes
   app.all('*', function(req,res){
       res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
   });

   // Start the server
   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
   ```
2. The [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) are very good, but if you need a video, this one: [Mean Stack Front to Back: Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZeDy2QI3OE&index=3&list=PLillGF-RfqbZMNtaOXJQiDebNXjVapWPZ&t=3s) is a nice code-along you can work with.  The Mongoose part starts about 90 seconds into the video.
3. This website gives a nice [CRUD Example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example) and also goes into Mongoose as well.